# skin modifier always creates bad topology

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology

I'm designing a character with a skin modifier, but no tutorials mention how hard it is to create good topology with it. Sometimes when I try modeling a tail, it creates a gaping hole over the tail. I would have to finick with it till it went away.
[image: Hole created to create example]And even when I have no holes and bad geometry, there is always bad shading involved[image: notice the grid shape on the chest] is it possible to fix this shading material without having to completely retopologize the mesh, if not, I'm open for any alternatives for character modeling as long as it's easy and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The skin modifier is not a super-functional, highly efficient feature. I consider it more of a tool to be used for creating a base mesh in a quick & dirty way. Though in some cases it is helpful, in most cases it's actually not. Sometimes you have to play around with the radius and the position of the vertex a lot even to create something simple. But the feature is not broken in any way. It's just the way it is and actually does the work that it's supposed to do. As for the bad shading part there are many different ways to fix it. Since that part of your question does not have one single sloution I won't answer that. Retopology is always the best option for such cases with the only drawbacks of being time consuming and tedious. But if  you want to do that in a quicker way there is a lot of existing content on the internet.

Comment: I never said it was broken, it's just incredibly tedious to get what you want.

Comment: @NathanielBrock I just meant it in the general sense.